# grails Two application deploy on tomcat Server heapSpace issue

Tags: grails, heap-memory

I have two grails(2.1.1) project deploy on the one tomcat(7.0.39).

I deployed a project on tomcat server, its worked but when i deployed other project on same tomcat , its generates heap Space error and and stop the tomcat server.

I have some idea to ignore this error by setting JAVA_OPTS. But I didn't have any rights to access Tomcat/bin directory.

Comment: You can set JAVA_OPTS on system classpath with `-server`. Generally, it goes like `-server -Xmx:1024m -Xms:512m -XMaxPermSize:256m`. The syntax may not be accurate as I am hard typing them down.:)

Comment: the C:\ProgramFiles\ApacheSoftwareFoundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs is

SEVERE: Context [/application] startup failed due to previous errors
Jul 08, 2013 10:19:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space